# SQL - select first in value set by priority?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly inexperienced in SQL and this seems like it must be an easy task, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Basically I want to select a single row from table A where field "someField" is in a pre-determined set "someSet", but I want it to look for each value in the set individually. For example, let's say "someSet" contains 5, 6, 9, 3. I would use a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE someField IN (5, 6, 9, 3) LIMIT 1
```

However, I want it to look for 5 first, then 6, then 9, then finally 3 if no rows have been found yet. Written as separate queries it'd look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE someField = 5 LIMIT 1
(if no results returned)
SELECT * FROM A WHERE someField = 6 LIMIT 1
(if no results returned)
SELECT * FROM A WHERE someField = 9 LIMIT 1
(if no results returned)
SELECT * FROM A WHERE someField = 3 LIMIT 1
```

Obviously using 4 queries (theoretically infinite queries) isn't very elegant, is there a way to make this into a single query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE someField IN (5, 6, 9, 3) 
ORDER BY FIELD( someField, 5, 6, 9, 3) 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know ORDER BY could be used like that. Thanks.

Comment: +1 from me.  It seems I learn something new about SQL every day.

Comment: cool, fantastic, awesome, ... wish i could give more than just +1